# What is just the plastic base of pin headers called?

Tags: connector, header, pin-headers

What is this part called? It's the plastic part of a row of pin headers, by itself.

I got a strip of these with a kit once but I don't know how to find more of them.

They're useful because stacking headers are often a bit too long.

[image]

Comment: That would have been a really impressive photo if you had the planet Saturn in the foreground :)

Comment: perhaps `pin carrier` ... you could simply pull pins from a pin header

Comment: @AndrewMorton Did you mean Jupiter maybe?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find pin ``` housing/insulators```? I would love to order some but cannot find any anywhere. If so, what name did you use for the plastic item of the pin headers?

Answer (score 1):

In some datasheets it is a "bandolier", and this is the most common term I've encountered when it's called anything. In [other documentation](https://suddendocs.samtec.com/prints/tlw-1xx-xx-xxx-x-xx-xxx-mkt.pdf?_gl=1*1362tpd*_ga*MTMwOTY1MTgwNS4xNjgyMDI4MTA3*_ga_3KFNZC07WW*MTY4MjIwMjIwMC40LjEuMTY4MjIwMzE4Ny4xMC4wLjA) it is just "Insulator", and bandolier can refer to another carrier. (I know this is an old question, but this question didn't have a correct answer).
I don't think I've ever seen a way to order just the bandolier, but maybe if you contact a supplier of pin row header (like Semtek), they might be able to offer something.
That said, it's possible to order a variety of header lengths & features, so that might be easier than adding bandoliers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the *stacking headers a bit too long* comment. Also I was not able to find anything in https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors-housings/319 or https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors-accessories/340 matching this description, not that such a search would be on-topic - EESE is somewhat strict on the non-shopping policy.

Manufacturers of pin headers typically call this the insulator or housing, made out of nylon or glass-reinforced PBT thermoplastic.

In production I think it'd be rare to need this kind of thing - a spacer with no populated pins - since you'd want the pins prepopulated to reduce assembly labour.